# Selenium Painfully slow

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a selenium script that scrapes data from a website. Sadly I can't share the site but I have noticed the same issue across several scrapers I have made. I have it set that if any exception is hit to just return `'Not Found'` as this is possible with the information I am looking for. When the information is found the script is extremely quick but when not it's slow as all can be.

Any suggestions to speed this up?

```
        form = driver.find_element_by_id('formSearchCriteria')
        form.send_keys(userID)
    
        searchButton = driver.find_element_by_id('phs-save-btn')
        searchButton.click()
    
        nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="jss137"]')
        nextButton[0].click()
    
        list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="balance-field"]')
        l = str(list[1].text)
    
        ignore_keys = ["User ","Identifier"]
        for ignore in ignore_keys:
            l = l.replace(ignore,"")
        return l
    except:
        return 'Not Found'
```

Comment: suggestions: try by_class_name instead by_xpath. Since you're getting the 0th jss137 button, you can say find_element which gets the 0th (no need to find_elements there). Also just noticing, is there a reason "User " has a space and "Identifier" does not?

Comment: Got it I'll have to try that then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is slow cause of

```
nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="jss137"]')
```

and

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="balance-field"]')
```

these two lines.

the things is they both return list.

Now, if a single element is found all is well. It'll work as expected.

But if not, it would wait whatever implicitwait you have in your suite.

so if you want them to be take less time, I would suggest you to decrease the ImplicitWait.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

10 or even less should work fine for you.

Comment: See I took out the wait because I thought that was the problem so maybe not? I believe it's actually because the first step in my try was to reload the site because there was no explicit way back to the form

Comment: `find_elements` they do not care about explicit waits (except for the worst one which is sleep(5)). They look for implicit wait, if that is set to some value, they would have to wait till the specified time in implicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the browser:

```
l = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll(".balance-field")].map(a => a.innerText)[1]')
```

This is potentially way faster depending on how many elements.

Comment: How do I parse xpath in that ?

Comment: You don't. This is a complete solution.

Comment: and if we can only find the web element with xpath then how come it's a complete solution  ?

Comment: as long we have a class name associated with html tag, we can use your solution, but I do not see it useful when we do not have class in html specified tag.

Comment: I disagree but I don't want to turn this into an argument. Any css selector will work, and WRT this question it's obviously not an issue.

Comment: I want to learn it man. I don't wanna put myself into any argument. yes your solution will work with css selector but will have an issue with xpath if it happens to be the "ONLY SELECTOR". Peace out !

Comment: I will definitely try that to see. The thing is though when I step through the code that doesn't get hung up at all. I'm sure it's not fast but the major hang up is when ```nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="jss137"]')``` is not found. Adjusting the waits as above stated helped but did not make a world of difference as I had hoped

Comment: @pguardiario Any chance you could point me to the lines this would replace? 
I commented out ```list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="balance-field"]')```and ```l = str(list[1].text)``` but it returned None when I know it shouldn't

Comment: Yes it replaces those lines. If it returns None, that means it's not there.